# UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture Failing when Photo does not exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I added the ability for users to add a photo to their profile as an avatar and ran into a problem.  I then added a process to show the photo when the user logs in.  However, I ran into a situation when a User is creating a new account. If a User creates an account and then tried to login, the Login failed.  It appears that the Query to get the photo does not handle nulls in this case.

I tried to check for the photo first, just to be sure, but the code is failing in that check step.

```
                            @if (UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture.Length > 0 && UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture != null)
                            {
                                <li class="nav-link" style="align-self: center;">
                                    <img style="width:40px;height:40px; object-fit:cover; border-radius:30px;margin-right:-30px;" src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture))">
                                </li>
                            }
```

This is the Error that is generated.  How do I safely check for the photo and only show one if it eixists, otherwise, gracefully display the menu without it?

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout+<>c__DisplayClass54_0+<<ExecuteAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in _Layout.cshtml, line 102

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout+<>c__DisplayClass54_0+<<ExecuteAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in _Layout.cshtml
+
                            @if (UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture.Length > 0 && UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture != null)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync() in _Layout.cshtml
+
    var stats = "active";
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: If you figure out where the null is you can handle.  This UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture.Length will give you an exception if the ProfilePicture is null.  Swapping the two conditions in the first if might take care of that.  If not, do the individual steps individually or look at the data in debug to determine what you can safely reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're evaluating the length of `ProfilePicture` before you're checking if it's null. So,

Change:

```
@if (UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture.Length > 0 && UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture != null)
```

To:

```
@if (UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture != null && UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture.Length > 0)
```

If you're using the latest version of C#//Razor, I'd recommend doing:

```
@if (UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)?.Result?.ProfilePicture != null && UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)?.Result?.ProfilePicture?.Length > 0)
```